# How to circle a textbox or box in crystal report based on formula field value?

Tags: crystal-reports

HI ,

I am having Y [yes] and N [No] in PDF and i need to circle anyone based on the boolean value in Crystal report.Any suggestions pls......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about a circle, but you can selectively put a square border around any field by going into the Format Editor, then under the Border tab. Then, under Color put in a formula like:

`if {YourField} = "Y" then crBlack else crNoColor`

My personal opinion is that if you just want to draw more attention to these fields, a conditional formatting of font color/style might be a more visually appealing way to go.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion..Its approved PDF template so i have to go with circle only ..i will try both of ur suggestion and see....

Comment: Another thought... You could underlay the field with a small picture of a circle that is the size and shape you want it and selectively suppress it. You'd want to make the image size (storage-wise, I mean) as small as possible, though.